# LINQ dynamic object creation without reflection (Activator.CreateInstance) and method invocation

Tags: linq, reflection, lambda, expression-trees, activator

I am writing pipeline logic. The idea is to create in instances of the object on fly and execute method Run methods in each case. I can do old way with reflections Activator.CreateInstance quite easy, but the performance is important in this case.

I looked thought  many code samples and tutorials I think I got right the Lambda expression correctly. I can figure out just the invocation part only. Thanks in advance.

```
namespace Pipelines
{
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Linq.Expressions;
using System.Reflection;

public interface IProcessor
{
    string Name { get; set; }
}

public interface IAspNetMembershipId : IProcessor
{
    Guid? Id { get; set; }
}

public class ProcessorOne
{
    public void Run(IProcessor args)
    {
        /* Do Something */
    }
}

public class ProcessorTwo
{
    public void Run(IAspNetMembershipId args)
    {
        /* Do Something */
    }
}

public class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var arguments = new AspNetMembershipId() { Name = "jim" };

        /* Pipeline1 Begin */
        Type type = typeof(ProcessorOne);
        NewExpression newExp = Expression.New(type);

        var p1 = Expression.Parameter(newExp.Type, "ProcessorOne");
        var p2 = Expression.Parameter(typeof(IProcessor), "args");

        MethodInfo methodInfo = (from method in newExp.Type.GetMethods() where method.Name.StartsWith("Run") select method).First();
        var invokeExpression = Expression.Call(p1, methodInfo, p2);

        Delegate func = Expression.Lambda(invokeExpression, p1, p2).Compile();

        /* Throws an exception. This not correct! */
        func.DynamicInvoke(newExp, arguments);
        /* or */
        func.DynamicInvoke(arguments);

        /* Pipeline2 Begin */
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
var arguments = new AspNetMembershipId() { Name = "jim" };

/* Pipeline1 Begin */
Type type = typeof(ProcessorOne);

NewExpression newExp = Expression.New(type);

var p2 = Expression.Parameter(typeof(IProcessor), "args");

MethodInfo methodInfo = (from method in newExp.Type.GetMethods()
                            where method.Name.StartsWith("Run")
                            select method).First();

var invokeExpression = Expression.Call(newExp, methodInfo, p2);
Delegate func = Expression.Lambda(invokeExpression, p2).Compile();

/* Doesn't throw exception any more */
func.DynamicInvoke(arguments);
```

Notice that I've supplied `newExp` directly to invokeExpression and left `arguments` as its only parameter.

Comment: It throws exception "Parameter count mismatch" still, try console demo above. Thanks for effort Damir!

Comment: Also if I change to code below it works. Something I am doing with  Expression.New(type) not right.                    var newinstance = System.Activator.CreateInstance(type);
func.DynamicInvoke(newinstance, arguments);

Comment: I tried my sample and it works. You missed the change I've done to `Delegate func` line - I removed a parameter there.
The problem indeed is with `Expression.New(type)`: it is an `Expression` but you need to provide an instance as a parameter to the lambda. That's why it works with `CreateInstance()`. It would also work like this: `func.DynamicInvoke(Expression.Lambda(newExp).Compile().DynamicInvoke(), arguments)` but it's more efficient to just keep it in a single expression as I've done above.

Comment: @JuozasBaltikauskas I'm also curious about the actual performance gain in comparison to using reflection. Caching compiled expressions might help here...

Comment: The perforce test was next in my list. I wanted to compare both version. As far I read on blogs the 'Activator' performance for 4.0 framework is significant up to 200x in may cases.